# A UITextField in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I've been trying to do this for a good few days now but to no avail. I've kind of got myself into a muddle too. Now I'm really confused how I should approach this. Where to start in a new .h and .m file. :/

My goal is to put a UITextField in a few UITableViewCell. Just like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Can somebody assist me with some kind of tutorial?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
        if (indexPath.row== 0) {
            UITextField *TextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            TextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            TextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                TextField.placeholder = @"mathie";
                [cell addSubview:TextField];
            }
return cell;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you adjust the height of the text field so that it fills the cell height to make it easy to select?

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a new NIB consisting of a UITableViewCell. Once you have that you can add any other UI elements to in, in your case the UITextField.

In your code you can call your custom UITableViewCell like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [saleItemsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndedifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = saleItemsCell;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: Hmm... Would it be easier to programmatically draw it? I've read a few forums that says loading nib files would slow the app down? Do you know how to draw them instead of touching the nib? Thanks.

Comment: Not really, if all you want to do is load a few simple UITextField objects I can't really see how that will have any major performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Check below apple default tutorial.

It will be helpful to you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009111

It's about "AdvancedTableViewCells".

It will ask to login to your apple account. So just login, and download example.

Comment: Sorry, that tutorial doesn't demonstrate the UITextField in the UITableViewCell. Do you know any others that are similar to doing the Login function shown by the pictures I posted? Thanks.

Comment: Ohh! ok. Currently, I don't have. If available then will let u know.